# dropdown button does not dropdown on hover

Tags: html, css, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>replit </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class=""dropin">
            <button class="dropdownbutton">dropdown button</button>
            <div class="dropdownmenu">
                <a href="#">List</a>
                <a href="#">List</a>
                <a href="#">List</a>
                <a href="#">List</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
.dropdownbutton{
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    padding:13px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropin{
    position:relative;
    display:inline;
}
.dropdownmenu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: orangered;
    min-width: 150px;
}
.dropdownmenu a{
    color: black;
    padding: 11px 15px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none ;
}
.dropdownmenu a:hover {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}
.dropin:hover .dropdownmenu{
    display: block;
}
.dropin:hover .dropdownbutton{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

I checked every single words and tags that I followed the process in YouTube by free code camp but it still does not work. This is the link to that YouTube video. (https://youtu.be/nu_pCVPKzTk?t=11602)

Comment: Two times double quote in your HTML you fix it <div class=""dropin">

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in the class name, here's the working demo: https://codepen.io/dreambold/pen/eYjZejd

So it should be `<div class="dropin">`